# Fastest possible algorithm to sum numbers up to N

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, integer, sum

I want a really **fast** algorithm or code in C to do the following task: sum all numbers from 1 to N for any given integer N, without assuming N is positive. I made a loop summing from 1 to N, but it is too slow.

Comment: Homework, ey...?

Comment: If it were homework, I doubt he would be asking, the answer is pretty trivial. It was probably one of those moments where you code up something then realize there's a formula that finds the thing you want.

Comment: Given that this is a standard sophomore level discrete math problem, I doubt it's homework... Unless, of course dada is secretly an elementary school student in math class with Gauss... B-)

Comment: wasn't there a recent thread (or maybe even a codinghorror blog post) about how programmers don't actually need to know math?  I think this question is a perfect illustration of why they do need to know math!  (and I use "math" in the sense most lay-people generally mean it, not in the sense that encompasses computer science, logic, etc)

Comment: Who has upvoted this question?

Comment: @qrdl:  Somebody going for the Electorate badge?

Comment: I'm shocked and appalled

Comment: @qrdl Who marked it as favorite !?!?!?

Comment: @Tom: Although it wasn't me, I use the favorite tool as a way of bookmarking posts that provide information which will be useful to me in the future. Perhaps somebody else wanted to remember the "trick" used in many of the answers.

Comment: @David - People going for Electorate can also vote _down_. Hint hint.

Comment: Don't you want to calculate 1+1+...+1 (*n* times) fast also?

Comment: @Chris Lutz:  I know, but upvoting seems nicer and doesn't cost rep.  The easiest way to get Electorate is to randomly upvote questions, which is another discussion that belongs on Meta.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If `N` is positive: `int sum = N*(N+1)/2;`

If `N` is negative: `int tempN = -N; int sum = 1 + tempN*(tempN+1)/2 * (-1);`.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, you should always perform premature optimization because it really makes a difference, and the compiler would never be smart enough to figure that out by itself. Also note that it might be faster because it does not do the same thing (you'd want `>> 1`).

Comment: No explanation on *how* this works? I'll give it a shot: `N/2` finds the average value of all numbers between 0 and N. We're starting at 1, so change that to `(N+1)/2`. Now that we have the average value, we just need to multiply that by the number of values in the sequence (N) (actually N-1(starting value)+1(1 to 2 contains 2 values, not 2-1=1), but N-1+1=N). So `N*((N+1)/2)`, reduced = `N*(N+1)/2`.

Comment: @erikkallen: (upvote for my smile).  Plus I believe the right shift is implementation-defined for signed data?

Comment: There's a good inductive proof of this, too, in case you need more than a simple demonstration.

Comment: wouldn't it be great if compilers were required and *able* to deduce such transformations? :)

Answer (score 24):

```
sum = N * (N + 1) / 2
```

Comment: But that's only O(1)!

Comment: @dancavallaro: not if you count bitwise operations its not!

Comment: you could always hard code the summation values of −32,768 to +32,767. Even fewer cycles :D

Comment: I do not think it works with negative number. If N is -3, this formula give 3 but -3+-2+-1+0+1 = -5

Comment: @gmatt is correct, this is actually `O(log N)`, unless you limit the value of `N`, in which case the naïve loop is `O(1)` as well.

Comment: @avakar: I upvoted your comment, but do `O(log N)` multipliers really exist? Wikipedia doesn't list any: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations

Comment: @erikkallen, my bad, I was thinking "at least `log N`", it should say `\Omega(log N)`.

Comment: If my understanding of wikipedia is correct, the Schönhage-Strassen algorithm (which appears to be the fastest discovered, practically usable algorithm) would geve a time complexity for this problem of `O(log N log log N log log log N)`

Answer (score 18):

The formula you're looking for is a more general form of the one posted in multiple answers to your question, which is an [Arithmetic Series/Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_series) with a ***difference*** factor of **1**.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Identities), it is the following:

[image]

The above formula will handle negative numbers as long as *m* is always less than *n*.  For example to get the sum from 1 to -2, set *m* to -2 and *n* to 1, i.e. the sum from -2 to 1.  Doing so results in:

```
(1 - -2 + 1) * (1 + -2) / 2 = 4 * -1 / 2 = -4 / 2 = -2.
```

which is the expected result.

Answer (score 6):

Just to complete the above answers, this is how you prove the formula (sample for positive integer but principle is the same for negatives or any arithmetic suite as Void pointed out).

Just write the suite two times as below and add numbers:

```
  1+   2+   3+ ... n-2+ n-1+   n   = sum(1..n)     : n terms from 1 to n
+ n+ n-1+ n-2+ ...   3+   2+   1   = sum(n..1)     : the same n terms in reverse order
--------------------------------
n+1+ n+1+ n+1+ ... n+1+ n+1+ n+1   = 2 * sum(1..n) : n times n+1

n * (n+1) / 2 = sum(1..n)
```

Comment: @Void: thanks but I've no merit, it's Gauss's classical proof.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with integer overflow I'd use the following function:

```
sum = (N%2) ? ( ((N+1)/2)*N ) : ( (N/2)*(N+1) );
```

Comment: clever... But this is *still* vulnerable to integer overflow. You aren't "dealing" with it, merely delaying it.

Comment: It will "delay" it as long as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Where n is the maximum integer you need to sum to.

The sum is (n*(N+1))/2

Answer (score 0):

`int sum(int n) {
return (n < 0 ? n *(-n + 1) / 2 + 1 :  n * ( n + 1) / 2);
}`

Answer (score 0):

have you heard about sequence & series  ? The 'fast' code that you want is that of sum of arithmetic series from 1 to N .. google it .. infact open your mathematics book..

Answer (score 0):

if |n| is small enough, a lookup table will be the fastest one.

or using a cache, first search the cache, if can't find the record then caculate the sum by using n * (n + 1) / 2(if n is positive), and record the result into the cache.